# how to make 1st tab of accordian open by default in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, accordion

```
interface Props{
data: string;
}    
interface State {
  expandedSection: string;
}



<AccordionToggle
              onClick={(event) => {
                this.onToggle(path, event);
              }}
              isExpanded={this.state.expandedSection === data}
              id={path}

            >
     <AccordionContent
              id="ex-expand1"
              isHidden={this.state.expandedSection !== data}
            >
     <p>{sampledata} <p>

            </AccordionContent>
```

There are multiple tabs of the accordian & I want 1st tab to open bydefault. Currently bydefault all the tabs are closed. If I will do the:

```
 <AccordionContent
              id="ex-expand1"
              isHidden={this.state.expandedSection === data}
            >
```

Then all tabs will get open bydefault.
 Can anyone help me with this, how to open just the 1st tab out of multiple tabs in accordian

Comment: What does data contains?

Comment: data is a string.

Comment: any condition which I can add in isHidden={this.state.expandedSection === data}, so that only the 1st tab shall remain open, and other tabs as closed.

Comment: Please show the component rendering the whole accordion's state

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `expandedSection` with the tab which you want to show and reverse your isHidden condition:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { expandedSection: 'tab1' }

  // ... other stuff
}
```

Comment: how will I differentiate between the tab 1 and other tabs?

Comment: Can you add full code, I'm not sure from where your `data` is coming.

Comment: data is the prop which is of type string. this is my onToggle method:  onToggle = (id, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (id === this.state.expandedSection) {
      this.setState({ expandedSection: "" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ expandedSection: id });
    }
  };